# Detect swipe direction on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I'm trying to detect swipe direction in Compose. I'm using the draggable modifier for this. But draggable allows only one direction to detect (Vertical or Horizontal). I want to detect swipes for all directions (left, right, up, down). Can anyone help me how can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Modifier.dragGestureFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/gesture/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).dragGestureFilter(androidx.compose.ui.gesture.DragObserver,%20kotlin.Function1,%20kotlin.Boolean)) detects dragging in any direction. Pass an instance of [`DragObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/gesture/DragObserver) and override [`onDrag`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/gesture/DragObserver#onDrag(androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset)). Here you can detect the swipe direction based on the [`Offset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/geometry/Offset.html). This object has `x` and `y` values, which are positive or negative based on the direction.

Here's what your code could look like:

```kotlin
Box(
  Modifier.dragGestureFilter(
    dragObserver = object : DragObserver() {
      override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset {
        val (x, y) = dragDistance
        when {
          x > 0 -> { /* right */ }
          x < 0 -> { /* left */ }
        }
        when {
          y > 0 -> { /* down */ }
          y < 0 -> { /* up */ }
        }
      }
    }
  )
)
```

To actually move the object, you would have to apply [`Modifier.offset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).offset(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) with values that are updated in `onDrag`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Note that "Modifier.dragGestureFilter has been deprecated. Use Modifier.pointerInput { detectDragGestures (...)} instead. Alternatively, use Modifier.draggable for one axis drags" (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.0.0-alpha02)

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [**`pointerInput`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#pointerinput_1) modifier controlling the dragging gesture with the [**`detectDragGestures`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#detectdraggestures) function.

Something like:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
            .size(100.dp, 100.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()

                    val (x,y) = dragAmount
                    when {
                        x > 0 ->{ /* right */ }
                        x < 0 ->{ /* left */ }
                    }
                    when {
                        y > 0 -> { /* down */ }
                        y < 0 -> { /* up */ }
                    }

                    offsetX += dragAmount.x
                    offsetY += dragAmount.y
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: I found I needed to access the mutable state offsets with `.value` to update them:
`offsetX.value += dragAmount.x`
 `offsetY.value += dragAmount.y`

Comment: Inside Box if we have scrollable content or LazyColumn, detectDragGestures is not working.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more modified way to get the direction without conflict horizontal swipes with vertical swipes, and to make sure to return the direction after the user end swiping.

```
var direction by remember { mutableStateOf(-1)}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consumeAllChanges()

                    val (x, y) = dragAmount
                    if(abs(x) > abs(y)){
                        when {
                            x > 0 -> {
                                //right
                                direction = 0
                            }
                            x < 0 -> {
                                // left
                                direction = 1
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        when {
                            y > 0 -> {
                                // down
                                direction = 2
                            }
                            y < 0 -> {
                                // up
                                direction = 3
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },
                onDragEnd = {
                    when (direction){
                        0 -> {
                            //right swipe code here }
                        1 -> {
                            // left swipe code here
                        }
                        2 -> {
                            // down swipe code here
                        }
                        3 -> {
                            // up swipe code here
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        
)
```

Comment: Inside Box if we have scrollable content or LazyColumn, detectDragGestures is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the corner directions, here's an angle-based algorithm:

```
fun swipeDirection(x: Float, y: Float): SwipeDirection {
    val angleDir = (atan2(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble()) / Math.PI * 180)
    val angle = if (angleDir < 0) {
        360 + angleDir
    } else {
        angleDir
    }

    return when (angle) {
        in 22.5..67.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.BOTTOM_RIGHT
        }
        in 67.5..112.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.RIGHT
        }
        in 112.5..157.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.TOP_RIGHT
        }
        in 157.5..202.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.TOP
        }
        in 202.5..247.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.TOP_LEFT
        }
        in 247.5..292.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.LEFT
        }
        in 292.5..337.5 -> {
            SwipeDirection.BOTTOM_LEFT
        }
        else -> {
            SwipeDirection.BOTTOM
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My modification:

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectSwipe(
        swipeState: MutableIntState = mutableIntStateOf(-1),
        onSwipeLeft: () -> Unit = {},
        onSwipeRight: () -> Unit = {},
        onSwipeUp: () -> Unit = {},
        onSwipeDown: () -> Unit = {},
    ) = detectDragGestures(
        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
            change.consume()
            val (x, y) = dragAmount
            if (abs(x) > abs(y)) {
                when {
                    x > 0 -> swipeState.intValue = 0
                    x < 0 -> swipeState.intValue = 1
                }
            } else {
                when {
                    y > 0 -> swipeState.intValue = 2
                    y < 0 -> swipeState.intValue = 3
                }
            }
        },
        onDragEnd = {
            when (swipeState.intValue) {
                0 -> onSwipeRight()
                1 -> onSwipeLeft()
                2 -> onSwipeDown()
                3 -> onSwipeUp()
            }
        }
    )

usage:

    Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectSwipe(
           onSwipeLeft = {

           },
           onSwipeRight = {

           },
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [detectHorizontalDragGestures/detectVerticalDragGestures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/understand-gestures#detect_full_gestures) modifiers to detect Horizontal or Vertical drag gestures,

> If you need to add more than one gesture listener to a composable, use
> separate pointerInput modifier instances

For Vertical Drag:

```
       Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectVerticalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    if (dragAmount > 0) {
                        // swipe down
                    }else {
                        // swipe up
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answers from @Gabriel and @J-Abdo I did something similar based on this answers, for me I need only left/right swipe and I added an "offset" with the min lenght that I want to be considered "swipe"

```kotlin
 BoxWithConstraints {
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        val minSwipeOffset by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                constraints.maxWidth / 4
            )
        }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            val (x, y) = dragAmount
                            offsetX += dragAmount.x

                        },
                        onDragEnd = {

                            when {
                                (offsetX < 0F && abs(offsetX) > minSwipeOffset) -> {
                                    SwipeDirection.Left
                                }
                                (offsetX > 0 && abs(offsetX) > minSwipeOffset) -> {
                                    SwipeDirection.Right
                                }
                                else -> null

                            }?.let(onSwipe)
                            offsetX = 0F
                        }
                    )
                }) {
        }
    }
```

and I'm using just a sealed class for the directions

```kotlin
sealed class SwipeDirection {
    object Left : SwipeDirection()
    object Right : SwipeDirection()
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a sealed class for the direction? Why not just an enum?

Comment: @thouliha in this case it does not matter, yes it can be a enum, but if in the future you need to pass the offset or more data you might need a sealed class, in my case I knew that I will pass more data, but as it is, yes a enum is also ok