# Detect strict horizontal drag gestures in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, gesture

When `detectVerticalDragGestures` and `detectHorizontalDragGestures` overlap (i.e. they belong to different composables, but share the same touch source), how can I dispatch events to `detectHorizontalDragGestures` only when the drag is *very* horizontal (i.e. the angle is more acute)?

When scrolling with our thumb, vertical swipes tend to be detected as horizontal ones.

[image]

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573008/detect-swipe-direction-on-jetpack-compose/66998079#66998079

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I actually found a solution: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1668543055698709?thread_ts=1667632578.033199&cid=CJLTWPH7S